# WCF Message.IsFault

Tags: .net, wcf, unit-testing, soapfault

I am trying to write a test and need to create a `Message` object with the `IsFault` property set to true. However, this property only has a getter. Does anyone know the best way to create a message where this property would be set to true?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Message.CreateMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195448.aspx) overload that accepts a [`MessageFault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messagefault.aspx) object.  Something like the following should work.

```
Message CreateMessage()
{
    return Message.CreateMessage(
        MessageVersion.Default,
        MessageFault.CreateFault(new FaultCode("fault-string"), "reason"),
        "action-string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly think about making a setter on the object with a proteced, internal or protected internal scope on. i.e.

```
public String MyProperty {get; internal set;}
```

Andrew

Reflection is another route, but I would think the first solution should work.

Andrew